# Create an Excel, outlook macro that when replying to an email, select the row of a spreadsheet to extract info

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook

hoping you can help here. I receive applications from customers in my applications inbox and was wondering how I can create a macro that, when i open the application, i fill out the relevant information on a spreadsheet, and when replying to the email, I CC the coworker that deals with the application. The message body will use a default signature template plus with the macro, I can enter the row number of the account i just entered, and within the signature, it pulls specific information from that row and puts it in the message body (there are some fields on the spreadsheet that i manually decide and enter where I cant get from the app itself)

Comment: We aren't a free code-writing site. What have you tried already?

Comment: I have 0 experience with macros. Can you at least give me a resource or tutorial for my problem, and I'll learn it?

Comment: Just google for it - there are many resources for VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your requirement seems to be too detailed, I haven't found a related article for your reference. Due to here we mainly discuss about general issue about Outlook desktop client, in order to solve your issue better, it's suggested to post your issue on [Outlook for developer forum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/office-vba-dev.html).There are many experts on VBA programming in Office, and you may get more related suggestion there.